# how do i measure throughput / bandwidth with command line or batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, throughput

it scares me to ask a question here without a working code to present for examination. I'm sorry to say I can't find any examples to try here or in Google.

Have you thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question?
*Yes

Sharing your research helps everyone.
*Can't find even one example to try or share.

This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and above all, it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!
*i started researching this yesterday morning and stopped at 11:00 at night and started again this morning. Before i got desperate and asked the question officially.

I've found over a dozen other throughput questions with no answer or (duplicate) or "don't ask stupid questions responses"

So that said please don't ban me for this seemingly unanswerable question.

I need the command or a short batch code for windows xp x86 family to find the throughput  or bandwidth of my lan (Local Area Network) PLEASE I'm not looking for ping. I know it exists in batch because i found one converted to exe but i couldn't open it to extract the bat file to examine it. 
Basicly it sent and received a file and calculated the average of Bytes/time. It showed a running total in cmd window but had no pause so when the file was done the cmd window closed. Sadly it had no log either.
If someone anyone can write a short bat, tell me the command line code for throughput, send me link to site with throughput bat examples or links to Google.com, howto.com, ask.com...ect and not mark my question with negative comments. I would be estatic. Thanks so much in advance for any helpful answer you give.

Here's a bat that might help any who read this question.

```
@echo off
MODE CON:COLS=15 LINES=10
color 0b
:input
set /p input=    
if %input% == %input% goto inputconfirm
:inputconfirm
echo ******************************************************************************************>>Helplog.txt
echo.>>Helplog.txt
echo ==%input%==>>Helplog.txt
echo.>>Helplog.txt
echo.>>Helplog.txt
%input% /?>>Helplog.txt
goto input
```

Comment: Try [iperf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iperf)

Comment: Downloaded iperf and am working on figuring out how to install and use it in a batch file. Thanks for the tip Mandrill.

Comment: If you want to calculate the actual transfer rate using batch then it's a matter of acquiring the time, transfer a file of known size, and then acquire the end time.  Calculate the bytes transferred in the timeframe you want.  Batch is limited to integer math less than 2^31 so a VBS script to do the calculation will help.

Comment: Thanks Foxdrive, I will look at VBS as of now I'm not familiar with it.  Actually what I'm trying to do is acquire the time using only the batch. I need a batch  (for the windows xp x86) that sends the file and acquires the time using only a batch (not c++, c#, java...ect.) Maybe my question should have started with   "Is it possible"

Comment: How did you go?  I wouldn't have seen your reply as you didn't use @foxidrive to alert me - it was luck that I was looking through older entries.  The person with the question gets an alert for all replies.

Answer (score 1):

Replace the timeout command (vista and higher) with a copy command and this will tell you the elapsed seconds.

You need to do the calculation with the filesize and elapsed time.

```
@echo off

:: get current seconds
call :gettime NowSec

timeout /t 10 /nobreak

:: get seconds after process
call :gettime NextSec

:: calculate elapsed seconds
set /a ElapsedSec=NextSec-Nowsec
echo %ElapsedSec% seconds elapsed
pause

goto :EOF
@echo off
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:DateToSecs %yy% %mm% %dd% %hh% %nn% %ss% secs
::
:: By:   Ritchie Lawrence, updated 2002-08-13. Version 1.1
::
:: Func: Returns number of seconds elapsed since 1st January 1970 00:00:00
::       for a given calendar date and time of day. For NT4/2000/XP/2003.
:: 
:: Args: %1 year to convert, 2 or 4 digit (by val)
::       %2 month to convert, 1/01 to 12, leading zero ok (by val)
::       %3 day of month to convert, 1/01 to 31, leading zero ok (by val)
::       %4 hours to convert, 1/01 to 12 for 12hr times (minutes must be
::          suffixed by 'a' or 'p', 0/00 to 23 for 24hr clock (by val)
::       %5 mins to convert, 00-59 only, suffixed by a/p if 12hr (by val)
::       %6 secs to convert, 0-59 or 00-59 (by val)
::       %7 var to receive number of elapsed seconds (by ref)
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
setlocal ENABLEEXTENSIONS
set yy=%1&set mm=%2&set dd=%3&set hh=%4&set nn=%5&set ss=%6
if 1%yy% LSS 200 if 1%yy% LSS 170 (set yy=20%yy%) else (set yy=19%yy%)
set /a dd=100%dd%%%100,mm=100%mm%%%100
set /a z=14-mm,z/=12,y=yy+4800-z,m=mm+12*z-3,j=153*m+2
set /a j=j/5+dd+y*365+y/4-y/100+y/400-2472633
if 1%hh% LSS 20 set hh=0%hh%
if {%nn:~2,1%} EQU {p} if "%hh%" NEQ "12" set hh=1%hh%&set/a hh-=88
if {%nn:~2,1%} EQU {a} if "%hh%" EQU "12" set hh=00
if {%nn:~2,1%} GEQ {a} set nn=%nn:~0,2%
set /a hh=100%hh%%%100,nn=100%nn%%%100,ss=100%ss%%%100
set /a j=j*86400+hh*3600+nn*60+ss
endlocal&set %7=%j%&goto :EOF
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

:gettime
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value') do set "dt=%%a"
set "YY=%dt:~2,2%" & set "YYYY=%dt:~0,4%" & set "MM=%dt:~4,2%" & set "DD=%dt:~6,2%"
set "HH=%dt:~8,2%" & set "Min=%dt:~10,2%" & set "Sec=%dt:~12,2%"
call :DateToSecs %yyyy% %mm% %dd% %hh% %min% %sec% %1
goto :EOF
```